# building image slider in CSS

Tags: html, css, slider

I need some help building an image slider in css/HTML.

My issue is that the five images i have to slide in are not hidden therefore they span the entire width of 2 webpages creating a horizontal scrollbar. I want the images sliding in to be hidden so there is no horizontal scrollbar.

```css
.slider {
  height: 350px;
}

.slider figure div {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.slider figure img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  left: 0;
  animation: 40s slidy infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <figure>
    <div class="slide"><img src="#"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="#"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="#"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="#"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="#"></div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your CSS? And any controls or anything? We need a working demo of what you have, so ideally you would include links to the images, too, so we can see the problem you've described.

Answer (score 0):

One really simple solution might be to give your `slider` class:

```
width: <someFixedWidth>px;
overflow: hidden;
```

That way anything that overflows your slider will be hidden.